# In XCode 8, how can I make an image button with padding?

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I have an button, and I told it which 'image' to use (setting the image in 'background' works too). I would like to make the image inside the button to be smaller than the button. I tried changing the content insets, the title insets, and the image insets, but none of them seem to be working. The content and image insets scoot the image around, but do not make it smaller.

I would like to accomplish this in the main.storyboard, and not do it programmatically, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but if you need any easy work around you can add the image as an UIImageView and then add a clear button over it with the padding u need